# Arc between two points: set angle "0" on top

Tags: javascript, canvas, geometry, trigonometry

I wrote a function in Javascript that draws an arc. It is based on the Bresenham circle algorithm and, while drawing the points, i check if they are between an initial and a final angle.

It works ok, but the angle "0" is on the "far left" side of the circle, while I'd like it to be on the top while still calculating the angle clockwise. How to do this? Thanks

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function pset(x, y) {
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}

function arc (x, y, rd, a1 = 0, a2 = 360) {
    let xx = rd;
    let yy = 0;
    let radiusError = 1 - xx;

    function inAngle(x1, y1) {
        const deltaY = y1 - y;
        const deltaX = x1 - x;
        const angleInDegrees = (Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI) + 180;

        return angleInDegrees >= a1 && angleInDegrees <= a2;
    }

    while (xx >= yy) {
        if (inAngle( xx + x,  yy + y)) pset( xx + x,  yy + y);
        if (inAngle( yy + x,  xx + y)) pset( yy + x,  xx + y);
        if (inAngle(-xx + x,  yy + y)) pset(-xx + x,  yy + y);
        if (inAngle(-yy + x,  xx + y)) pset(-yy + x,  xx + y);
        if (inAngle(-xx + x, -yy + y)) pset(-xx + x, -yy + y);
        if (inAngle(-yy + x, -xx + y)) pset(-yy + x, -xx + y);
        if (inAngle( xx + x, -yy + y)) pset( xx + x, -yy + y);
        if (inAngle( yy + x, -xx + y)) pset( yy + x, -xx + y);

        yy++;

        if (radiusError < 0) {
            radiusError += 2 * yy + 1;
        }
        else {
            xx--;
            radiusError+= 2 * (yy - xx + 1);
        }
    }
}

arc(50, 50, 20, 0, 45);
arc(50, 70, 20, 0, 90);
arc(50, 90, 20, 0, 180);
```

```html
<canvas width="128" height="128" id="canvas"/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add the following two lines to the beginning of your `arc` function:

```
a1 += 90;
a2 += 90;
```

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


function pset(x, y) {
  ctx.fillRect(x, y, 1, 1);
}

function arc (x, y, rd, a1 = 0, a2 = 360) {
    a1 += 90; // add this line
    a2 += 90; // add this line
    let xx = rd;
    let yy = 0;
    let radiusError = 1 - xx;

    function inAngle(x1, y1) {
        const deltaY = y1 - y;
        const deltaX = x1 - x;
        const angleInDegrees = (Math.atan2(deltaY, deltaX) * 180 / Math.PI) + 180;

        return angleInDegrees >= a1 && angleInDegrees <= a2;
    }

    while (xx >= yy) {
        if (inAngle( xx + x,  yy + y)) pset( xx + x,  yy + y);
        if (inAngle( yy + x,  xx + y)) pset( yy + x,  xx + y);
        if (inAngle(-xx + x,  yy + y)) pset(-xx + x,  yy + y);
        if (inAngle(-yy + x,  xx + y)) pset(-yy + x,  xx + y);
        if (inAngle(-xx + x, -yy + y)) pset(-xx + x, -yy + y);
        if (inAngle(-yy + x, -xx + y)) pset(-yy + x, -xx + y);
        if (inAngle( xx + x, -yy + y)) pset( xx + x, -yy + y);
        if (inAngle( yy + x, -xx + y)) pset( yy + x, -xx + y);

        yy++;

        if (radiusError < 0) {
            radiusError += 2 * yy + 1;
        }
        else {
            xx--;
            radiusError+= 2 * (yy - xx + 1);
        }
    }
}

arc(50, 50, 20, 0, 45);
arc(50, 70, 20, 0, 90);
arc(50, 90, 20, 0, 180);
```

```html
<canvas width="128" height="128" id="canvas"/>
```